# MySQL selecting multiple table

Tags: mysql

Am having a MYSQL db and i want to select accounts thats connected in table users and table friends

this is my query

```
SELECT id(distinct FRIENDS.ID) FROM FRIENDS JOIN USERS ON FRIENDS.ACC IN (FRIENDS.ACC, FRIENDS.CONTO) 
    WHERE #USER FT11 IN (FRIENDS.ACC, FRIENDS.CONTO)
```

This is the error i get

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

```
TABLE USERS

ID USER_ACC NAME
1  FT11     JANE
2  FT22     FRED
3  FT33     KEN


TABLE FRIENDS

ID ACC  CONTO
1  FT11 FT33
```

ACC can be my account or CONTO can be my account
so i want to select or check these accounts am connected with on same column in FRIENDS table

Comment: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use".  The error is pretty much tell you what to do.  You can't write a query with whatever syntax you want, and expect MySQL to understand it .

Comment: what you are trying to do is not clear from your attempt at a query.  please explain, and show desired results.  you may have to add more sample data to make your desired results helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you want.

```
SELECT u1.user_acct, u1.name, u2.user_acct, u2.name
FROM Friends f
JOIN Users u1 ON u1.user_acc = f.acc
JOIN Users u2 ON u2.user_acc = f.conto
```

Comment: i tried it and not working

Comment: @michkent "Not working" will not help me help you.  Not working how???  What result do you want to see from your example above?

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code snippet:
SELECT DISTINCT F.ID FROM FRIENDS F JOIN USERS U ON F.ACC = U.USER_ACC OR F.CONTO = U.USER_ACC
WHERE U.USER_ACC = 'FT11';

Try using this.